# Is my water pump short cycling?

Tags: plumbing

I live in a low mains water pressure area, so I had to install an [Aquabox](https://waterpartsdirect.com/product/aquabox-500ltr-v-water-pressure/?c=b121d766c7b9) water tank in my garage which has a Genyo controller and submersed pump.

It's 3 years old now, but I've only recently noticed that the pump is cycling approx. every minute, even when there is no water being used, is this normal?

I assumed it's not, below is a list of things I have checked:

1. I've turned off all our toilets in case there's any of them running
2. The underground MDPE pipes are all sound (recently dug up and replaced and issue was occuring before)
3. The tank is being filled and there's no failures reported on the Genyo controller
4. I've pressed the valve on the [expansion vessel](https://www.unventedcomponentseurope.com/reliance-aquasystem-arb18-litre-potable-expansion-vessel-c-w-bracket-xves050055.html/) located in the house and it releases air and not water, so doesn't appear to be damaged.

There are no obvious signs leaks in the system, so I'm stumped at this stage and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would need to check the air pressure in the tank.  Read manual or google for your tank for instructions.  Just because pipes were replaced, does not mean there is no problem, less likely, but still might be.  If pressure is correct, might be a problem with pump or controller.

Comment: @crip659 The pressure in the big tank or the expansion vessel?

Comment: Probably both, if like most pressure tanks, air pressure is adjusted according to water pressure.  Should be in the manual.  Air pressure cushions time that the pump needs to come on.

Comment: Where is the location and condition of check valves? If not leaking out of the pipes then that leaves returning to the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the state of the tank, it should not cycle **at all** with no water being used. You have a leak, probably a leaky check valve (so water goes back to the pump tank) if you are QUITE certain no water is being used. That's typically built into the pump outlet for a submersible pump.

If not, then you have something leaking and using water you're unaware of - water softeners and toilets being my prime suspects, as they don't tend to leak in such a way that you find a puddle to notice the leak. But you already tried the toilets. If you have a valve you can shut all water off with after the pressure tank ("expansion vessel"), try it, and see if the problem remains.

Air pressure in the tank should be 2-3 PSI below pump cut-in with the water side drained (incoming water & pump shut off, no pressure in the water pipes.) But the tank isn't the main problem if no water is being used and the pump is cycling.

Comment: Letting the air out can mess things up but a bike pump can be used to get the pressure back to 2-3 psi below cut-in  or pump turn on . This answer hits the problems I have seen.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I was initially looking for a big leak but I looked at my outdoor tap and seen there was a small leak on it, like a spray of mist - isolating that solved the problem